# Python http server interaction

Tags: python, http

I have a project that I am putting together it is working well so far.

But I am a bit lost on where to start python wise. The basics of the projects are A lighting system that is controlled by an Arduino over a wireless link (Already setup) that receives commands from a python program through serial over a xBee network (This part is coded and working). I want the project controllable over the internet.

I was thinking about running it so that the python program runs an http server which is fairly easy to setup.

Here is where I am having trouble as I have not played with python in the past. How do I get the program to respond to request and run code depending on what was clicked on the page?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please

Comment: What is the problem with taking some Python web framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a server application using a framework like Tornado that listens for messages on an arbitrary port.

However it sounds like you want to build a web interface. For this you should just pick a web framework. My favourite micro framework is [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#quickstart). Their quickstart I just linked to shows how easy it is to get a simple site running.

Then you would write a function for each action in the user interface. And each of those functions would be activated when the user clicks a link (or a button) that visits the associated URL.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/dim_lights/<room>')
def dim_lights(**kwargs):
    dim_lights_for_room(kwargs['room'])
```

The `'index.html'` template would contain links like `<a href="/dim_lights/lounge">Dim the Lights in the Lounge</a>.`

Does that makes sense?

Comment: +1 for Flask. It's an amazing framework.

Comment: Thanks for the information, sorry about the delay been out of the house for a few days, this seams to be the route than I need to take. I will do some study into it

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with serial ports and web apps in a single python app then I would use twisted. It's event loop deals with serial ports as well as web requests etc....  It is a framework of sorts too.  Most other "frameworks" do not support serial ports (as part of the event loop - ie callbacks on receiving data)  out of the box.  http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a web-based application that link with your project, you can try to use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) as the framework and perhaps use [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) as the http server. Read Flask documentation to understand Flask better. There is a tutorial for python web deveveloper newbie on that site.

Then you need to write some scripts for your hardware and you can integrate it with your web app.